subspace homeomorphic to a dense subspace, is itself dense?
Let $X$ be a metric space, $A, B\subset X$ be its subspace. Under the same metric, $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic in the subspace topology. If one of them is dense in $X$, does another dense in $X$ as well?
From a category view point, it seems to be true, since the diagram has to be commute, but I cannot prove neither using pure topology or properties of metric space.

Think of a counter-example in unit interval.

Would probably be a more interesting question, whether there is any infinite, $T_2$ space, which satisfies this condition. For sure, it cannot be separable, regular, T2, first countable.

You probably had in mind that there exists a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ such that $f[A] = B$, in which case the answer would be yes. That would explain all the talk with diagrams and categories (or would it...?)

@Ulli Do you have in mind an infinite $T_1$ example? The best I can think of is $T_0$.

@David Gao: the integers with the cofinite topology is a $T_1$ example.

@Ulli Ah, you’re right, I somehow forgot any infinite subset is dense in that case. Yeah, that works. Thanks!

Not true.
Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)(A)$. Note that $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan:\mathbb{R}\to (-1,1)$ is a homeomorphism. Also, if $U$ is open in $B$, then $U = B\cap V$ for some $V$ open in $X$ and thus $$\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(U) = \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(B\cap V) = \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(B)\cap \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(V)$$
thus
$$\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(U) = A \cap \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(V)$$
and thus $\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\right)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$. Therefore $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\colon A\to B$ is continuous. Similarly, one can show that $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan$ is an open map. Since it is bijective, $A \cong_{\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan} B$. It is known that $A$ is dense in $X$, however, $B$ is not dense in $X$ since the open set $(1,2)$ doesn't contain any elements from $B$.

This is far more complicated than necessary. $X = [0, 2]$, $A = (0, 2)$, $B = (0, 1)$ is already an example. The homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ can be just linear scaling.

For another example, let $X$ be any infinite space with the discrete topology. Let $A=X$ and $B$ any proper subset with the same cardinality as $X$.

@ChoripánConPebre How is $\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$? $\mathbb{R}$ isn't compact...........

@monoidaltransform Thanks for pointing that out! The homeomorphism is between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-1,1)$ (not $[-1,1]$). I have edited the answer.
